# Creating Bonjour services for the Finder

Tags: python, macos, bonjour

I am playing around a bit with Bonjour and for prototyping I use the Pybonjour library, which seemed to work like a charm for my first trials. However, when I try to create a service that is visible in Finder, I fail hard. I used [this page](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/qa/qa2001/qa1312.html) as a reference for the service identifiers to use. The document specifies which services are browseable in Finder.

I tried  `_afpovertcp._tcp` and it appeared instantly in Finder. The two more interesting ones (`_webdav._tcp, _ftp._tcp`) however, does not. Am I missing some required component, or is this a configuration error (e.g. some built-in firewall enabled by default?). I am using Snow Leopard 10.6.3 for the test.

I also tried the server part on an Ubuntu machine with exactly the same result. Additionally, I noticed that the Terminal.app discovers the FTP server (on both the Ubuntu and OSX server).

EDIT: Update: SMB (`_smp._tcp`) works, same behavior as AFP.

I am seeing these possibilities:

- Finder requires something more than just the service string
- Discovery of FTP and WebDAV services is turned off by default and needs to be enabled somehow
- Discovery of FTP and WebDAV has been removed in snow leopard (let's hope not!!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this some more a while ago, and I found out that it appears that some Bonjour services are no longer(?) available in Snow Leopard and Lion. I could not find a relevant documentation about it, but I provide my result as a help to those were looking for the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the Finder, try the Bonjour Browser http://www.tildesoft.com/Programs.html .  It is a utility for discovering all services with Bonjour.  Also of use is the command line utility dns-sd which can be used to simulate publishing services that Bonjour can discover.  The command

dns-sd -R "Test Printer Service" _printer._tcp "" 666

simulates a printing service that bonjour will discover.  Swap out _printer._tcp with any of the service types to simulate them.

I'm building a iPad app that uses the Bonjour services, so I'm still learning about them too.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I used a similar tool, and the service is discovered. Also, it is shown in e.g. terminal. But that beats the purpose of it all. I want to be able to browse the service in Finder, without requiring the end user to type any URL or install third-party software.